# How to send Json to a webservice from pc/RPI with live data from embedded device(serial)

Tags: json, shell, arduino, raspberry-pi, raspbian

**TL;DR: How do I grab the serial data from the embedded device, convert it to Json and send it off as an http request to my webservice?**

I'm making a project where my plan is to take sensor input from an embedded device, and then pass that info (by serial/usb connection) through either a laptop or a Raspberry Pi and convert it to Json and send it to a webservice in asp.net c#, where it gets stored in a database, and then the data can be shown on a website, so the visitor can see live data from embedded devices sensor on the site and also be able to see what the sensor measured yesterday, last month, or the average for a extended period of time, or a graph.

It might be easier to illustrate what I'm talking about:

[image]

The Win7 PC / Raspbian OS part is optional, it can be using either one.

**It's the blue arrows on the image that this question is about.** And its only the connection between the first 3 boxes on the image, rest is just to give an idea of how the setup is thought out to be.

There are a few options, as I see it, as to which methods could work. But I am unsure about how to implement them and what programs to use for it.

First one is to log data to a file on the PC/RPI and then have some shell script either listen for changes and then combine a Json string with the newly added info to the file and send it of to the webservice.

Second one is to somehow take the Serial data from the embedded device and have some shell script or program listen for any data coming from the embedded device and converting it to Json, and sending it of to the webservice. The pro's by this method would be omitting the extra "file-step", but it would make the system more vulnerable to any interruptions in the connection.

I'm using an Arduino as the embedded device, but since it goes through the usb, it could be any embedded device. I have a temperature sensor connected to my Arduino, and it's the readings of my temperature sensor I want to update live on a website.

Which of my two ideas are best? Or is there a better setup?
Does anyone have experience with doing something like this? Or maybe have an idea how I can do what I'm trying to do ? Or just a nudge in the right direction, as to which approach you think is best, or what programs I could/should use.

Comment: Open-ended questions are offtopic here but I'll bite. It would be easy instead of a shell script to have a Tcl script on the RPi or the PC read data from the a serial port in an event loop, digest it and then periodically talk to the MySQL database to store it. The web service could then be limited to serving data to the visitors. Check out the examples at http://wiki.tcl.tk/10042 (you probably won't need the TCP/IP part here) and http://wiki.tcl.tk/20343.